# Safari Extension available via a web server

Tags: web, publish, safari-extension

I am working on safari extension and want to publish the extension on my website. I am using following code so that user is able to download the .safarixtz file and then install it:-

```
<%String filename = "<safariextz file path>" ;        
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream safariextz");

String disHeader = "Attachment;filename=test-safari.safariextz";
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);

// transfer the file byte-by-byte to the response object
File fileToDownload = new File(filename);
response.setContentLength((int) fileToDownload.length());
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileToDownload);
int i = 0;
while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    out.write(i);
}
fileInputStream.close();%>
```

But the resulting file can not installed on the safari browser and throwing error:-

Safari can't install this extension
An error occurred while installing this extension

I also want that installation start the moment user click on Install link like in apple gallery.

Thanks

Comment: What language/platform are you using for you web server?

Comment: It might be that your download code is not downloading all the bytes correctly. Have you tried comparing the checksums ?

Comment: Language looks like [JSP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_syntax.htm) @StevenSchobert

Answer (score 0):

this is because your extension has error. can you please share your extension so that I can help you checking it.

also, do not use these code to serve the extension file. you do not need to to this.

all you need to do is
- upload your extension to your server's public file, and you will get an url of it
- modify your server config file (Apache or some other http server can be configured easily with adding a line in the config file ) to hanlde the .safariextz file

you are done.

first make sure you have no error in your extension.